# Make sound stop when button is pressed iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, avaudioplayer

I have multiple buttons that play sounds using AVAudioPlayer. If you press one, and press another before the first ends, they are both playing at the same time. How would i make it so if you press two buttons, only the last pressed button's sound plays?

Comment: possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5246948/avaudioplayer-uibutton-second-touch-stop-current-audio-play

Comment: sorry- didn't see that question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know the exact code, but you may have to bool something or try AudioServicesDisposeSystemSoundID. It will stop the sound immediately.

Comment: Hi I have the same issue. Can you tell me how you have solved this using AudioServicesDisposeSystemSoundID or the bool you said here. I am doing same but in swift but no success.

Answer (score 0):

Before you start the new song you have to do:

```
[song1 stop];
song1.currentTime = 0;
```

And do that for all the songs that could be possibly playing.  Then you can make the new song play.  (The current time sets it to start from the beginning if you play it again.)  hope that helps :)